# What does this hand and number represent?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion, the-elder-scrolls-series

I'm playing Elder Scrolls: Oblivion and I just noticed something I've never seen before. On my Hand-to-Hand skill description, there is a hand with a number 4 in the lower right corner:

[image]

It's there even when I have nothing equipped, no non-birthsign active effects, and none of my other skills (minor or major) have it. I'm an Imperial.

What does it mean? (I'm not uisng any mods)

Comment: I've searched all over for the answer to this. Zero info found. It could be damage dealt, race build bonus, or item bonus.

Comment: Isn't it the power of your hand to hand damage? Try adding something that would increase your hand to hand damage and check if that value changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the base damage of your weapon — your fists — and is rated on the same scale as the base damage of other weapons.

> The damage currently done when your character uses Hand to Hand can be seen in the skills section of your journal: if you highlight Hand to Hand, the number visible next to a fist icon is the damage.

Your fists' base damage is derived from your Strength and your HtH skill level, so it will improve as you advance. A base damage of 4 is a point less than what's dealt by an [Iron Dagger](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Dagger#Daggers). (The benefit being that HtH deals fatigue damage as well, and doesn't weigh anything.) More information is in the [Hand to Hand Oblivion skill article in the UESP](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Hand_to_Hand).